# Segmentation Fault in C++ With for Loop

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

I am making an Ant simulation with SDL2 and when I run my code it soon crashed giving me a segmentation fault. I believe this is from trying to access *negative* values in an array. I tried to make it so the Ant can't do this by giving an if statement checking its value on the "grid" I made out of squares. I added an if statement on line 420 to try and stop my theory but it didn't do anything. Does anyone see the issue here?

My Grid Initialiation:

```cpp
struct Wall
{
    bool IsAlive;
    int Health = 10;
    SDL_Rect Rect;
    bool isAnt;
    bool IsHome;
    bool IsFood;
};
```

This is where I set up the rects:

```cpp
int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1440; i += 4)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 795; j += 4)
        {
            SDL_Rect Rect = {i, j, 4, 4};
            wall[count].Rect = Rect;
            wall[count].IsAlive = true;
            if (i < 10)
            {
                if (j < 10)
                {
                    wall[count].IsAlive = false;
                }
            }
            count++;
            
        }
    }
```

And this is where I do the Ant Digging:

```cpp
void Break(int AntID, int SurroundingSqr /*Clockwise*/)
{
    if (SurroundingSqr == -199)
    {
        if (A[AntID].PosID > 100)
        {
            wall[A[AntID].PosID + SurroundingSqr].Health--;
            if (wall[A[AntID].PosID + SurroundingSqr].Health == 0)
            {
                wall[A[AntID].PosID + SurroundingSqr].IsAlive = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        wall[A[AntID].PosID + SurroundingSqr].Health--;
        if (wall[A[AntID].PosID + SurroundingSqr].Health == 0)
        {
            wall[A[AntID].PosID + SurroundingSqr].IsAlive = false;
        }
    }
    
}
```

If you want to see all the code you can go to this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/GameBakerStudio/09fdabca56465d54dcdb59031bcdfdd0)

Comment: Q: "I believe this is from trying to access negative values in an array."  A: I believe that would be a good guess!  SUGGESTION: familiarize yourself with your debugger.  Look at the traceback when it fails.  If it's an array access, ensure the index is between 0 and n-1.  You absolutely need to IDENTIFY THE FAILING LINE, and troubleshoot from there!

Comment: A[AntID].PosID + SurroundingSqr > 100-199 ie negative

Comment: @paulsm4 I have tried the debugger. It never works... If I get it working I will sue it though! I tried to stop my theory buy adding the if statement on line.. 420.. in break(). What do you think? Would this do anything?

Comment: Learning your debugger is ONE OF THE MOST ESSENTIAL SKILLS you need for effectively developing software.  Please feel free to post questions to StackOverflow if you encounter problems or have any specific questions as you work with it.  In the meantime 1) Be sure to compile your program for the debugger (e.g. "-g" for the GCC compiler).  2) run your program inside the debugger.  If it crashes, it will give you a traceback.  The traceback should give you the exact line that crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should include all the headers you need. You are missing `#include <ctime>`.
2. You have *undefined behavior* because of indices running out of bounds, as can be seen when running your program compiled with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined`:

   ```
   ant.cpp:350:34: runtime error: index -199 out of bounds for type 'Wall [572397]'
   ant.cpp:356:32: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'Wall [572397]'
   =================================================================
   ==3989611==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: global-buffer-overflow on address 0x00000042fae4 at pc 0x000000405540 bp 0x7ffe896fa2e0 sp 0x7ffe896fa2d8
   READ of size 1 at 0x00000042fae4 thread T0
       #0 0x40553f in MoveLeft(int) /home/ted/proj/stackoverflow/ant.cpp:356
       #1 0x407f87 in MakeAntActions() /home/ted/proj/stackoverflow/ant.cpp:213
       #2 0x402687 in main /home/ted/proj/stackoverflow/ant.cpp:102
       #3 0x7ff7a0671b74 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x27b74)
       #4 0x40293d in _start (/home/ted/proj/stackoverflow/ant-g+++0x40293d)
   ```

I would start nesting out the problem by following the call chain from line

- 102: `MakeAntActions();` ➔
- 213: `MoveLeft(i);` ➔
- 350 and 356 (where it croaks)

```
if (wall[A[AntID].PosID - 199].IsAlive)  // line 350 index -199
if (wall[A[AntID].PosID - 1].IsAlive)    // line 356 index -1
```

So, `A[AntID].PosID` is `0` at the time the program reaches these lines which creates these negative indices - and negative indices are not allowed.

Compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` to get hints like this.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is using g++.  But your suggestion for compiling with `-g` (debugger symbols) and `-fsanitize=address,undefined` (enabling the "address sanitizer") is excellent advice.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks! I was actually assuming that OP is using clang++.because I think that's the most commonly used on macos.